# Predicted values from a series of linear models

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, broom

Hi there: I have a series of linear models in a data frame constructed using tidyr and dplyr. It looks like below. How would I go about generating predicted values from each model with a fixed set of newdata?  In reality I have 10 dependent variables, but only two independent variables

```
#random data
x1<-rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=5)
x2<-rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=2 )
y1<-rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=1)
y2<-rnorm(100, mean=3, sd=1)
#create test data farame
df<-data.frame(y1, y2, x1, x2)
#create models
df%>%
  gather(dv, value, y1, y2, -x1,-x2) %>%
  group_by(dv)%>%
  do(mod=lm(value~x1+x2, data=.))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to get the predictions as a column in a data.frame using `do`.  The difference from the other answer is the use of `data.frame` to get the predictions in a column.  You can add in the `dv` variable to this dataset to keep things straight.

```
df %>%
    gather(dv, value, y1, y2, -x1,-x2) %>%
    group_by(dv)%>%
    do(mod=lm(value ~ x1 + x2, data=.)) %>%
        do(data.frame(dv = .$dv, pred = predict(.$mod, newdata = df)))

Source: local data frame [200 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

      dv     pred
   (chr)    (dbl)
1     y1 4.936012
2     y1 4.948939
3     y1 4.992472
4     y1 4.733290
5     y1 4.921581
6     y1 5.115699
7     y1 4.981135
8     y1 4.837326
9     y1 4.641484
10    y1 4.739197
..   ...      ...
```

The down side of that (to me) is that you don't have the data used for the predictions with the actual predicted values.  You could certainly `cbind` to the prediction dataset, but another useful option is to use `augment` from package *broom* within `do`.  In this second alternative I use `augment` within the first call to `do`, although it's not required.

You can give the dataset you want to predict with/add the predictions to using the `newdata` argument within `augment`.  In this example I used the dataset `df2` (just the dependent variable columns of your `df` dataset).

```
library(broom)
df2 = df[ , 3:4] # Dataset for predictions
df %>%
    gather(dv, value, y1, y2, -x1,-x2) %>%
    group_by(dv)%>%
    do( augment(lm(value ~ x1 + x2, data=.), newdata = df2) )

Source: local data frame [200 x 5]
Groups: dv [2]

      dv        x1       x2  .fitted   .se.fit
   (chr)     (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)
1     y1  5.863764 6.201406 4.936012 0.1521102
2     y1  4.419014 7.028888 4.948939 0.1936563
3     y1  7.917369 6.081930 4.992472 0.1255001
4     y1  4.338864 4.019565 4.733290 0.1842635
5     y1 13.307611 2.674705 4.921581 0.1757911
6     y1 14.986879 4.666154 5.115699 0.1614377
7     y1 12.941636 3.679022 4.981135 0.1409247
8     y1  7.474526 4.088868 4.837326 0.1310659
9     y1  2.136858 3.706184 4.641484 0.2357699
10    y1  9.307190 1.885127 4.739197 0.2008851
..   ...       ...      ...      ...       ...
```

Comment: Better answer than mine. Thank you, I am still learning dplyr and that is helpful. (deleted my answer since I think yours is more elegant and better written)

Comment: This is amazing. Can you explain why the data and the newdata arguments need to be specified? To me, the model should be fit to the original data frame (df) but the predicted values should be produced with the newdata (df2)

Comment: @spindoctor You only need the `newdata` argument when using `augment` for prediction.